# Convert String to Bitmap

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

In my project i will retrieve image from mysql database and display it to `Imageview`. In database I have saved the link of image. So I need to convert `String to Bitmap` to display image. But i got error like `setImageBitmap is undefined for the type of String`. I am not sure what mistake i have done.

**Code:**

```
Bitmap b=StringToBitMap(Qrimage);
imgg.setImageBitmap(b);      

public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String image){
           try{
               byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(image,Base64.DEFAULT);

               InputStream inputStream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(encodeByte);
               Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
               return bitmap;
             }catch(Exception e){
               e.getMessage();
              return null;
             }
     }
```

Comment: can you show your String  which is converting to bitmap ?

Comment: can you post the string "Qrimage" that you're trying to convert ?

Comment: Is your link to image is a web url or device specific path?

Comment: you have a url link of image and have to convert it as image am i right?

Answer (score 11):

change your function

```
 public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
   try{
       byte [] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
       return bitmap;
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       e.getMessage();
       return null;
   }
 }

// second solution is you can set the path inside decodeFile function 
viewImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("your iamge path"));
```

hopefully it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

If you get bitmap = null, you can use:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(pic, Base64.URL_SAFE );
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```