# how to convert hashmap data to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, hashmap

is it impossible if I want to transform the hashmap data to bitmap?
my data is like this

> 02-01-2022 15:20:04.038=[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

from this program

```
Map<String,Object> rightDataDict = new HashMap<>();
rightDataDict.put(String.valueOf(formatter.format(date)), Arrays.toString(r_data_double_arr));
```

Update our 2D array data:

> [[0.0, 28.0, 80.0, 61.0, 8.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 31.0, 37.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 46.0, 63.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 63.0, 44.0, 26.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 30.0, 80.0, 59.0, 5.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 39.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 52.0, 64.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 65.0, 44.0, 24.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]....]

Our 2d array looks like this, the size will be 50*89

Answer (score 0):

Found something relevant:

[Convert String to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005948/convert-string-to-bitmap)

Try to convert or change `<String, Object` into `<Integer, String>` or `<String, String>`.

And add this before the method in the link above:

```
String output="";
for(String s:rightDataDict.values()){
    output+=s;
}
```

But if you don't want that idea... Try this:

```
String output="";
for(Object o:rightDataDict.values()){
    output+=o; /*If you hit an iceberg, try this: output+=(o+"");*/
}
```

Now with your 2d array just replace the `for-each loop` with this:

```
String output="";
for(int i:intArray){
    output+=(i+"");
}
```

Comment: my data is not in the image, but just hashmap data as above. is it possible or not if I want to transform it into bitmap format?

Comment: It's possible, just trust the method and it will trust you.

Comment: But bear my word, if that data doesn't equal to any bitmap format available, then it will never be read properly by a common image viewer.

Comment: If we now have a 2d-array filled with integer number, how can we transform it to bitmap or bytebuffer. Thanks for ur help man.

Comment: @P76107077杰凱力艾 Okay man, just replace the for-each loop above with a for loop, I will edit my answer to suit your latest question.

Comment: @P76107077杰凱力艾 I already edited it, take a look!

Comment: After the for-each loop, just feed the output variable to the method that I linked above, there are many ways presented in there.

Comment: Hi @JumperBot_ ! Really appreciate ur reply. So if we have a string(look like 2d array) which we have edited above, and then we can put it into the stringtobitmap function in the link? Cuz I'm not quite sure what the string should look like before put into the function to become a bitmap. Thanks again!

Comment: @P76107077杰凱力艾 That's good as it should be! Try it out, if it fails then it's your data that failed, because other people already tried it out and went out successful.